# Does the sublinearity of $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ imply $\inf \frac{f_n}{n}=\lim\frac{f_n}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I have a sequence such that 
$$
f_{n+m} \leq f_n + f_m
$$

can I say that
$$
\inf \frac{1}{n} f_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} f_n?
$$
If so, can you help me prove it? If not, under what conditions would this be true?

Comment: Do we also have $f_n\geq 0$? Don't mind, it is not really important.

Comment: The statement in question is know as Fekete’s lemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}\frac{f_n}{n}=\alpha$. For any $\varepsilon>0$ we have that $f_n\geq (\alpha-\varepsilon)n$ holds for every $n\geq 1$. Additionally there is some $N$ such that $f_N\leq (\alpha+\varepsilon)N$, and by sub-linearity we know that $\frac{f_n}{n}\leq(\alpha+\varepsilon)$ holds at $n=N,2N,3N,4N,\ldots$, too. Let $M=\max_{k\in[1,N-1]}f_k$. Always by sub-linearity we have that for any $n\geq N$
$$ \frac{f_n}{n}\leq \alpha+\varepsilon+\frac{M}{n} $$
holds, hence for any $n\geq\frac{|M|}{\varepsilon}$ we have that $\frac{f_n}{n}\leq(\alpha+2\varepsilon)$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary,
$$ \inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}\frac{f_n}{n}=\alpha\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{f_n}{n}=\alpha $$
as conjectured.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a better title for this question? I wasn't sure what to title it and I'd like to make it more relevant.

Comment: @user187815: I performed an edit in such a direction. Feel free to improve it.